# Adobe AEM - Full copy of environment

Tags: adobe, aem, aem-6

I'm new at Adobe AEM.

So I want to clone all content of a environment, I know I have to create packages, download it and then import on my local env. and install them.

My problem is I am lost of which folders should I create a package to download content, assets, templates etc.

I have download:

- /content/{site}
- /content/content-fragments/{site}
- /conf/{site}

But still missing pages and content, any thoughts about this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check `/content/dam` for resources like images.

Answer (score 0):

Also, /content/experience-fragments/. Be careful with the DAM packages, if you bring really all the assets, it can be both intensive for your server and huge to install. So, if you are cloning a environment, there are better alternatives. For local development, you do not need all the content.